# Running hci lescan with timeout breaks the command

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluez

So the command `sudo hcitool lescan` outputs bluetooth addresses until ctrl+c is pressed. I want to have the command run for 20 seconds and capture the output. I tried running timeout 10 sudo hcitool lescan, but that gives me the following error: `Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error`

However, if I put `sudo hcitool lescan` in a `.sh` file and then run `timeout 10 sh_file_name`, it finishes executing without an error.

I tried making a `.sh` file with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(timeout 10 ./test.sh 2>&1)
echo "$output"
```

However, now that gives me the original error.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?